# how to remove duplicated entries on a line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

For example I have this:

SH890FDP.number1

SH890FDP.number2

SH890FDP.number3

SH890FDP.number4

But i only want to keep one line containing the first part which is the same on each line:

SH890FDP.number1

Please help me with a solution to this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are going through the list manually, you might just want to search and replace using the regular expression search like `SH890FDP.+$`.

And here's something else I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769100/598560